What is $P(\text{A} \mid \text{E})$ in Bayesian net $\text{A} \to \text{C} \to \text{E}$?
For Bayesian network $\text{A} \to  \text{C}  \to \text{E}$.
$\text{E}$ depends on $\text{C}$, which depends on $\text{A}$.
I am confused at getting $P(\text{A} \mid \text{E})$.
I am applying Bayes' Theorem $\dfrac{P(\text{E} \mid \text{A})P(\text{A})}{P(\text{E})}$
$$\begin{align}
P(\text{E} \mid \text{A})&=P(\text{E} \mid \text{C})\, P(\text{C} \mid \text{A})\, P(\text{A})+P(\text{E} \mid \sim \text{C}) \, P(\sim \text{C} \mid \text{A}) \, P(\text{A}) \\
&=\{P(\text{E} \mid \text{C}) \, P(\text{C} \mid \text{A})+ P(\text{E} \mid \sim \text{C}) \, P(\sim \text{C} \mid \text{A})\}\, P(\text{A}).
\end{align}$$
Putting this in the above formula:
$$P(\text{A} \mid \text{E})= \frac{\{P(\text{E} \mid \text{C}) \, P(\text{C} \mid \text{A})+ P(\text{E} \mid \sim \text{C}) \, P(\sim \text{C} \mid \text{A})\}\, P(\text{A}) \, P(\text{A})}{P(\text{E})}$$
Is it right?

Almost. By the law of total (conditional) probability we have $P(E|A)= P(E|A, C)P(C|A)+P(E|A, \neg C)P(\neg C|A)$. Also, from the graph we infer the conditional independence $A\perp E | C$ and $A\perp E | \neg C$, so $P(E|A)= P(E|C)P(C|A)+P(E|\neg C)P(\neg C|A)$. So you have a factor $P(A)$ too many.
